# Compiler/linker option to launch Visual Studio on exception

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I use Visual Studio 2013 but most of the time I use `nmake` to compile and link console applications that I also launch from a Command Prompt window.

Of course, if I run into a bug and the program crashes, I am not inside Visual Studio and cannot see what caused the bug.

Are there compiler (cl.exe) and linker (link.exe) flags in Visual Studio that would allow me to start Visual Studio in debug mode and put me straight into the offending code?

My alternative is to build a new Visual Studio project with the same flags I used to compile and link the program so I can reproduce the problem. This is very time consuming and, most of the time, I wouldn't need to save the project.

I'm hoping that there is a way to compile and link my code with the proper flags such that all the necessary debug information would be available in the executable, so I would be prompted to open Visual Studio when the program crashes with an exception, allowing me to quickly fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I needed two things done:

1. In Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Debugger... I had to enable the just-in-time (JIT) debugger.
2. In Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Action Center > Problem Reporting Settings, I had to choose "Each time a problem occurs, ask me before checking for solutions."

Once both were done, I purposefully tested a C program with a divide by zero. A window popped up offering me to debug the program, and Visual Studio automatically came up showing the source code where the problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you have to recompile and rebuild in VS. In Visual Studio you can attach dynamically to any executable

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx

so when you encouter a bug and you have the crash windows, you should be able to attach to your process and see the callstack; maybe you'll have to specify where to find the sources,

Or maybe  are you locking for the DebugBreak win API ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx

Off course all that suppose that you compile/link in Debug

Comment: Thanks sandwood. I will try to attach to the executable as you suggested. Is there a way to compile/link in such a way that VS will automatically know where to find the sources? Also, to compile/link in Debug which specific compiler/linker flags to I need to include? Thanks!

Comment: Well... didn't quite work. I explicitly added a division by zero to test things out. As I ran the program in the console window a window popped up saying "program.exe has stopped working... Windows is collecting...", followed by another window asking me whether I wanted to send more information about the problem. I left both windows untouched, went into Visual Studio, attached to the executable, but there was no stack. Clearly, I'm still missing something when compiling/linking.

Comment: First thing, do you have the .pdb file corresponding to your executable ? I do not know/use the nmake but I presume with it you can compile/build in Debug. If so you should see , aside where you .exe is generated, the .pdb file.

Comment: It seems you can pass build option to name on the command line, like this 
nmake.exe -f makefile.vc BUILD=debug

That should generate the pdb

Comment: My makefile is hand-written. So I explicitly put all compiler/linker flags I need there. In other words, there is not target BUILD=debug.

Comment: So I guess I need to know how to compile all my files and build my static library (that's what I've been asked to build), as well as my main program - i.e., which compiler/linker flags - so I end up with a proper pdb file that would be automatically found no matter which directory I start my executable from.